# jQuery caching selectors

Tags: jquery, caching, selector

I have div with id `#wrapper` and all element are inside it.
I'm caching wrapper by doing

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');
```

Now any time i want to make a selector or reference an element, i do

```
$wrapper.find('#whatever').click(....
```

By doing this i avoid wrapping with jQuery object again, so any selector i do in the future will be based on the cached `$wrapper`. But on the other when i use `find()` with the cached $wrapper, i know it will search all elements inside `#wrapper`. My questions is whic is better better, use cached variable along with find then issue click event, or just simply do `$('#whatever').click(..`

`whatever` can be either a class or id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use it where `whateverID` is an `ID` then `$('#whateverID').click(..` would give you slightly better performance, however if `whateverCLASS` is class or anything other than `ID`, `$wrapper.find('whateverCLASS').click(....` will be better since the traversing will be limited to specific container which is subset of the whole DOM

Answer (score 2):

Performance wise it is better to cache the "wrapped" version of the DOM element. Otherwise you'll be traversing the DOM every time you do `$("#myElem")` which can get very expensive if your DOM is really big or you are doing it a lot of times.

Comment: isn't find() also expensive. I did a performance test and it seems like the non cached version is faster. http://jsperf.com/testttttt

Comment: I think your test has a problem, because you are executing `var $wrapper = $("wrapper")` and `$wrapper.find("#editable").hide()` on every iteration.

Comment: That's exactly my question. Is find not a good thing to use with cached variable since it will reference all element with the specified id or class.

Comment: Well in a practical example, you would cache the reference to `#wrapper` before you enter any loop.

Answer (score 2):

The two are not completely equivalent. Your caching version is actually the same as `$("#wrapper #whatever")`, and won't match the element with id `whatever` if it isn't contained in the wrapper div.

If you always intend for the `#whatever` element to be within the `#wrapper`, then `$('#whatever')` is actually probably faster than your cached version - finding elements by ID involves a single function call, `getElementById`, which is available in all browsers, while your cached version involves checking the hierarchy to make sure the matched `#whatever` element descends from `#wrapper`.

Comment: All elements are contained inside #wrapper

Comment: In my question i noted that whatever could be a class or id. Are you saying it's better to not cache.

Comment: @Pinkie It is better not to cache when dealing with ids. With classes, it will be faster to use your caching approach. The best thing to do would be to test this yourself. It's extremely trivial to try both versions and measure their relative performance.

Answer (score 2):

What about $('selector', context) so ...

```
$('#whatever', $wrapper)
```

searches the DOM only in the context of $wrapper

Don't search the whole tree when you can search a single branch or twig.

Comment: I think that's functionally equivalent to `$wrapper.find('#whatever')`