# Select sub element using cached selector (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is somewhat related to my inquiry, but doesn't quite cover what I need to understand:

[jQuery caching selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845862/jquery-caching-selectors)

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
</div>
```

I cached the DIV selector: `var md = $('#myDiv');`

How can I access the `<img>` sub element using the cached DIV selector?

For eg, something like:

```
md.('img').fadeOut();
```

or

```
$(md + ' img').fadeOut();
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7wogdumq/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select your `md` jQuery object, then use either the `find()` or `children()` method to search its hierarchy for the elements "below" it:

```
var md = $('#myDiv');
//the next two lines do the same thing
md.find('img').fadeOut();
md.children('img').fadeOut();
```

Which is better for you? Well...this expounds on [the differences between find() and children()](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/difference-between-find-and-children-in-jquery/), and the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/648004/1430996) give you some helpful performance metrics to help decide.

See a [working example of `find()` and `children()` at http://jsfiddle.net/o8Ldzo5z/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/o8Ldzo5z/4/)

Please note, convention is to assign jQuery objects to variables prefixed with a "$": `var $md = $('#myDiv');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- [`find`](http://api.jQuery.com/find) `// generic method for finding descendants`
- [`children`](http://api.jQuery.com/children) `// for immediate children`

The above as well as, `filter` can also be used.

```
md.find('img').fadeOut();
```

Comment: `find()` is correct, but I don't think `filter()` works like that: http://jsfiddle.net/o8Ldzo5z/1/